# how to get user id of a facebook user in a facebook iframe application?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-iframe

I'm developing a Facebook iframe/Facebook Connect application with PHP client library. In my index page, I check if the user is logged in by using `require_login()`.

```
 $user_id = $facebook->require_login($required_permissions = 'user_location,publish_stream,email,read_stream,user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,user_events,user_groups,
```

user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_status,user_photos);

Thus I get the $user_id of the user in that page. But in the subsequent pages, If I use require_login() to get the user_id, some prablem occurs and the page ie not redirected.
The page gets refreshing and nothing is displayed.

So I tried using `$user_id = $facebook->get_loggedin_user();` but then I dont get the user id in the variable.

If I use `$user_id = $_GET[fb_sig_user];` , sometimes I get the value, sometimes I dont. Please suggest me the proper method to get the user_id in other pages too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. Posting it so that it might help someone else ..

Adding `$facebook->require_frame();` before using the `$user_id = $facebook->require_login()` syntax in the main page and the `$user_id = $facebook->get_loggedin_user();` in the other pages, solves the problem.

For more details refer to this thread:
http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=218858